# How to make background body overlay when use twitter-bootstrap popover?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I used this twitter-bootstrap popover:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:11px; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus"  data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
              Upgrade
```

The output:

[image]

How I can make the background overlay like bootstrap modal? My expected output

[image]

I use this jquery to popover

```
$(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement : 'bottom'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting some more code would be nice.

This should work. Use some jQuery or AngularJs or any other framework to make the **.overlay** initially hidden, then to make it visible when needed.
If you need help, comment.

If it helps, +1.

**EDIT**

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'bottom'
  });
  $("#buttonright").click(function() {
    $("div.overlay").toggleClass("on");
  });
  $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
      $("div.overlay").removeClass("on");
    });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.overlay.on {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
}
button {
  margin-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <button id="buttonright" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Upgrade</button>
</div>
```

This is the new snippet with the full code and behaviour.

Comment: Can you show me how it shows when the button was clicked?

Comment: I meant when button 'upgrade' clicked.

Comment: I have edited the post. Any more questions? I am here to help.

Answer (score 0):

rather than binding to a click event, which can be a problem if you have multiple popover on click button triggers. Use bootstrap show and hide methods to display your overlay.

Here is an example below:

```
   $(function(){
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html : true,
        template: '<div class="popover extra" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
        content: function() {
          var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
          return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
        },
        title: function() {
          var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
          return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
        }
    }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $( "body" ).append( "<div class='overlay'></div>" );
      console.log("done");
    }).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    $( ".overlay" ).remove();
    })
    
});
    body {
    padding: 100px;
}
.popoverss {
  position: absolute;
background-color: red;
}
.overlay {
position: fixed;
left:0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 42%);
z-index: 90;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bakersingh/7j0bxyd1/2/